# Criar campo id com CheckBox DataTable Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Tenho o seguinte datatable:

```
function retorna_cliente()
{
    $(".mostra_clientes .table").dataTable({ "bDestroy": true }).fnDestroy();

    $('.mostra_clientes .table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 4,
        "ajax": {
            "url": url_base + "clientes",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "defaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' value='AQUI VEM O ID' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/>"},
            { "data":"nome"},
            { "data":"data_nascimento"},
            { "data":"telefone"},
            { "data":"celular"},
            { "data":"cpf"},
            { "data":"endereco"},
            { "data":"email"},
        ], language: {
            "sProcessing":   "Carregando...",
            "sLengthMenu":   "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":  "Não foram encontrados resultados",
            "sInfo":         "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":    "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
            "sInfoPostFix":  "",
            "sSearch":       "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":          "",
            "oPaginate": {
              "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
              "sPrevious": "Anterior",
              "sNext":     "Seguinte",
              "sLast":     "Último"
            }
        },
        "bDestroy": true,
    });//.fnDestroy();
```

No campo checkbox preciso pegar o ID que vem do dada.id para editar e excluir um cliente. Como que eu faço isso usando o DataTable? Como que eu passo o ID para este checkbox?

Achei um exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/, mas não entendi muito bem a lógica.

Comment: Eu uso Datatable  com retorno um pouco diferente, mas o ID retorna sempre como DT_RowId se não me engano, não sei se consegui lhe ajudar....

Comment: @LeoNogueira. Como que seria? Eu preciso pegar o ID de cada cliente e coloca-lo naquele checkbox para poder editar o cliente. Tem algum exemplo concreto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode na linha que cria a coluna que contém o checkbox, usar uma função.

Por exemplo:

```
"columns": [
            {
                "data": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+data['id']+"' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/>";
            },
```

Comment: OK. Só uma correção que fez com que funcionasse: Em data[0], coloquei data['id']